# Delegate With Null Instance Encounters Exception With Yield Return

Tags: c#, class, struct, delegates

I've encountered some strange behavior trying to create a delegate from a function that returns an IEnumerable.  In the first three instances I can pass in a null "this" and receive valid results, however in the combination of a struct and yield return I hit a runtime NullReferenceException.  See the code below to replicate the issue.

```
class Program
    {
        public delegate IEnumerable<int> test();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var method2 = typeof(TestClass).GetMethod("testReturn");
            var test2 = (test)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(test), null, method2);
            var results2 = test2.Invoke();
            Console.WriteLine("This works!");
            
            var method = typeof(TestClass).GetMethod("testYield");
            var test = (test)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(test), null, method);
            var results = test.Invoke();
            Console.WriteLine("This works!");
 
            var method3 = typeof(TestStruct).GetMethod("testReturn");
            var test3 = (test)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(test), null, method3);
            var results3 = test3.Invoke();
            Console.WriteLine("This works!");
 
            var method4 = typeof(TestStruct).GetMethod("testYield");
            var test4 = (test)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(test), null, method4);
            var results4 = test4.Invoke();
            Console.WriteLine("This doesn't work...");
        }
        public class TestClass
        {
            public IEnumerable<int> testYield()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    yield return i;
            }
            public IEnumerable<int> testReturn()
            {
                return new List<int>();
            }
        }
 
        public struct TestStruct
        {
            public IEnumerable<int> testYield()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    yield return i;
            }
            public IEnumerable<int> testReturn()
            {
                return new List<int>();
            }
        }
    }
```

It *does* work when I pass in default(TestStruct) instead of null, however I will not be able to reference the proper type in this way at runtime.

EDIT: I was able to fix this issue by using Activator.CreateInstance instead of null to create a dummy object dynamically.  I'm still interested as to what is different about the yield return that is creating this issue, though.

Comment: Struct instance methods have a hidden byref `this` parameter. If you pass null (which a struct cannot be) you get the exception. `default()` works because there's not *no* struct, there's a *default* one. You'd need a delegate type that accepts a single `ref` parameter of the struct type

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I assumed it was something like that, thanks.  Although the first delegate created from a struct instance method does work with a null reference.  For some reason adding the yield return introduces the issue.

Comment: Well... Yield return creates a state machine under the hood and that means it's allocating classes to do the work. Likely something in the machinery that then goes to dereference the field from within the display class or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterator methods that use `yield return` [create a state machine](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/IteratorBlockImplementation), which means that local variables, including `this`, are lifted into fields of a hidden class.

In the case of iterator methods of classes, the `this` is obviously an object reference. But for structs, `this` is a `ref` of the struct.

**Looking at the compiler-generated in [Sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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), you can see why `TestStruct.testYield` fails and not `TestClass.testYield`.**

The only reference that `TestClass.testYield` makes to its `this` argument is:

```
IL_0008: ldarg.0
IL_0009: stfld class C/TestClass C/TestClass/'<testYield>d__0'::'<>4__this'
```

This does **not** involve a dereference of `this`, which in your case is `null`.

**Why does Reflection not throw an exception?** Because it is not required to do so. An object reference is allowed to be `null`, even if it is the `this` parameter. C# will throw on a direct call because it always generates a `callvirt` instruction.

---

**Whereas `TestStruct.testYield` actually de-references its `this` argument,** this is because of the inherent difficulty in lifting a `ref struct` into a field:

```
IL_0008: ldarg.0
IL_0009: ldobj C/TestStruct
IL_000e: stfld valuetype C/TestStruct C/TestStruct/'<testYield>d__0'::'<>3__<>4__this'
```

---

**Technically speaking, a managed `ref` pointer is not allowed to be null (see  [ECMA-335 Section II.14.4.2](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf)), so it is somewhat surprising that Reflection even allows the call.** Obviously it can always be done with unsafe code.

Comment: Thanks for this in-depth explanation.  Sounds like the actual strange behavior here is that the exception is not also thrown on TestStruct.testReturn.

Comment: @LFH no, Reflection is not required to do a null-check. C# does it automatically at call-site with a `call.virt` instruction. What is surprising is the `ref` pointer being null, which is simply not allowed, see [ECMA-335 Section II.14.4.2](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf) Have elaborated further